# jquery explode effect not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here I am creating nav menus using div and jquery. I tried few things here but didn't get the result what exactly I want. You can see in a fiddle when I click a link those two scrollbars (x & y) will appear (I don't want that) and I didn't get the jquery explode effect correctly. Its sliding from left. How to achieve the jquery explode effect properly? and I have done very lengthy code for jquery explode effects is that correct?

[You can see my codes in JSFIDDLE. I tried this. But didn't get the result what exactly I want.](http://jsfiddle.net/CKNrv/3/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#showhome").click(function(){
         $("#firstdiv").show( "explode", 
                     {pieces: 8 }, 600 );
      });
      $("#showhome").on('click', function() {
                      $("#seconddiv, #thirddiv, #fourthdiv, #fifthdiv, #sixthdiv").hide();
                });
});
```

this is code i'm using for jquery explode effect. you can see remaining jquery, html, css codes in jsfiddle..

Comment: Tell me simply. What you actually want?

Comment: i want to use jquery explode effect when user click the link. I posted my codes in jsfiddle.

Comment: Check out this simple code, http://api.jqueryui.com/explode-effect/

Comment: @KiranRS: I already achieved this explode effect using two links. Here i'm trying to do this effects for navigation menus. if one link opens remaining five links should hide.

Comment: try this, function showHide(divID) {     $("div").not("#" + divID).fadeOut(3000);

Comment: This appears to be a bug.  While I have managed to reduce your code to maybe 11 lines, my answer would not solve your riddle, so I can't post it.

Comment: @Daedalus: did you tried anything? do you know why its not working properly?

Comment: @Indian It appears to be a problem with the effect.  Nothing you can solve without significant knowledge of how jQuery UI works.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 functions doing the same thing.

```
$("#showhome").click();
```

and

```
$("#showhome").on('click', handler);
```

`.click()` is just a shortcut for `.on('click', handler)`.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

You can add them together like so:

```
$("#showhome").click(function () {
    $("#firstdiv").show("explode", {
        pieces: 8
    }, 600);
    $("#seconddiv, #thirddiv, #fourthdiv, #fifthdiv, #sixthdiv").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use toggle like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#showhome").click(function(){
         $("#firstdiv").toggle( "explode", 
                     {pieces: 8 }, 600 );
      });
   });
```